# Bootstrap Local with Prepros

Tags: html, css, sass, bootstrap-4, prepros

Just started coding.
So I need to manually convert a PSD into HTML and SCSS. We also need to minify with Prepros.
I added the file template, selected stylesheet bootstrap.css (with bootstrap.min.css as output). Now there's an other stylesheet called css/all.min.css, and I do not know what the original file is to input into Prepros. Also, is there anything else I need to do, to make it work?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

**bootstrap.min.css** is the original file of bootstrap to use. hope it helps.